# Which IDE is best for Verifone EDC programming

Tags: ide, verifone

I am currently Using source insight ide for Payment EDC programming. but it is not a good ide. i am not able to compile directly from that ide. i am currently adding project files, then making the programming changes and compiling using batch script. this process is very error prone and tedious.

I searched on net for IDE's to develop EDC application in verifone devices, but i could not get any concrete answer. verifone does not have its own ide. even if it has its may be for their internal use.

Can you please help me in suggesting which IDE can be used for verifone EDC application development. i tried in eclipse and qt creator. but could not generate lib symbols in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with "EDC" in relation to VeriFone, but for my Verix, VerixV and eVo projects, I use Visual Studio.  You'll have to finesse it a bit to get it to work, but after a few tweaks, you will be all set up and ready to go and you can build from within the IDE, have it sign your output, move files to the appropriate locations, etc.  You'll also get intellisense (with some caveats) and the ability to set it to build for different platforms based on the solution configuration.

If you decide to take this route, here are some settings you'll need (and I'll be honest--I don't remember which of these I explicitly set and which were already that way).  To find them, right-click the project and go to properties. Let's say you're program is called `myProgram`

1. Under "General" be sure the configuration type is `Makefile`
2. "VC++ Directories"

   1. Executable Directories = $(PATH);
   2. Include Directories = $(EVOVMAC)\include;$(EVOVMAC)\template
3. "NMake"

   1. Build Command Line=NMAKE /i /f myProgram.smk Configuration=$(Configuration)
   2. Rebuild All Command Line=NMAKE /i /f myProgram.smk /a Configuration=$(Configuration)
   3. Output=myprogram.exe
   4. Include Search Path=(the include files to myprogram);$(EVOVCS)Include;$(EVOSDK)\include; $(EVOACT)Include;$(EVOVMAC)Include;$(NMakeIncludeSearchPath)

Note that you may need to tweak that last one a bit

That should be enough to get you started.  There are several other things you can do to your make file to automatically do this or that, depending on your needs.